# Passing a String's True/False Boolean Value into a Functions Argument

Tags: php, boolean, parameter-passing

Thank you so much for reading and responding if you can.

- In one function I test a condition and make a string 'true' or 'false', which then I make a global variable.
- Then I call another function with that string as the parameter
- Within that function's if statement, I want to test based off the strings boolean value of 'true' or 'false'

  ```
  $email_form_comments = $_POST['comments']; // pull post data from form

  if ($email_form_comments) $comments_status = true;  // test if $email_form_comments is instantiated. If so, $comments_status is set to true
  else $error = true; // if not, error set to true. 

  test_another_condition($comments_status); // pass $comments_status value as parameter 

  function test_another_condition($condition) {

      if($condition != 'true') {    // I expect $condition to == 'true'parameter
        $output = "Your Condition Failed";
        return $output;
       }

  }
  ```

My thinking is that $condition will hold a 'true' value, but this is not so.

Comment: Does $string actually have a value in it? Otherwise $status will be false obviously.
Also, I wouldn't use a string of 'true', I'd just use an actual boolean.

Comment: you probably meant to use `if($condition != true)` as outlined in another comment, checking for PHP's TRUE constant, instead of a string literal and `$status = true;` so it's hard to say what you're looking to do here. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Comment: I have left this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key here is PHP will evaluate empty strings as false and non-empty strings as true, and when setting and comparing booleans make sure to use constants without quotes. Use `true` or `false` not `'true'` or `'false'`. Also, I suggest writing your if statements so they will set alternate values on a single variable, or in the case of a function return an alternate value when the condition fails.

I made some small modifications to your code so that your function will evaluate true

```
// simulate post content
$_POST['comments'] = 'foo'; // non-empty string will evaluate true
#$_POST['comments'] = ''; // empty string will evaluate false

$email_form_comments = $_POST['comments']; // pull post data from form

if ($email_form_comments) {
  $comments_status = true;  // test if $email_form_comments is instantiated. If so, $comments_status is set to true
} else {
  $comments_status = false; // if not, error set to true. 
}

echo test_another_condition($comments_status); // pass $comments_status value as parameter 

function test_another_condition($condition)
{
    if ($condition !== true) { 
      return 'Your Condition Failed';
    }

    return 'Your Condition Passed';
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have updated my post to attempt to clarify. I do not want to set a string to true, but test if a string is instantiation, then set the string to true so I can test later.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you! I see I was not echoing the test_another_condition either, so that did not help.