# How to pass a boolean argument to a function to act as a switch?

Tags: php, function

My apologies if the title isn't clear, but I find this difficult to describe. Basically, I have a function that looks for an instance of a class (the school kind) given a class ID number and a date. The function can also create a new class instance if desired.

```
function get_class_instance($class_id, $date, $create)
```

Inside the function is a database select on the **class_instances** table using the **class_id** and **date** as arguments. If a matching **class_instance** is found, its ID is returned. If none is found, there's a conditional for the **create** argument. If it's true, a new **class_instance** is created using a database insert and its ID is returned. If false, nothing is changed in the database and **false** is returned.

I'm still a beginner with PHP and coding generally, so I'm thinking there is probably a better way. The issue is that when calling the function, it might not be clear to someone why there is a boolean being passed.

```
$original_cinstance_id = get_class_instance($original_class_id, $original_date, 1);
```

Comment: look up "enumerators". I dont think its really that much of a problem, but depending on the nature of the flag being passed, you can create a helper data structure that basically gives boolean or integer flag syntax meaning.

Comment: are you looking for something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298241/passing-a-strings-true-false-boolean-value-into-a-functions-argument)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a String's True/False Boolean Value into a Functions Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298241/passing-a-strings-true-false-boolean-value-into-a-functions-argument)

Comment: Passing boolean flags to functions to make them do two different things instead of just one is considered a Code Smell in Robert Martin's Clean Code book. The suggested better option would be to have two functions `get_whatever` and `create_whatever`.

Comment: @Gordon, I think you're right. I knew something didn't feel right, and you articulated the reason. Also, had I thought to use "flag" in my searches, I might have seen as much. Anyway, if you'd like to put this information into an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing boolean flags to functions to make them do two different things instead of just one is considered a [Code Smell](http://wiki.c2.com/?CodeSmell) in [Robert Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Cecil_Martin)'s [Clean Code book](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code). The suggested better option would be to have two functions `get_whatever` and `create_whatever`.

While a Code Smell depends on context, I think the boolean flag smell does apply in this case, because creating something is different from merely reading it. The former is a Command and the latter is a Query. [So they should be separated](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html). One changes state, the other doesn't. It makes for better semantics and [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) to split them. Also, it will reduce the [Cyclomatic Complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the function by one branch, so you will need one unit-test less to cover it.

Quoting https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FlagArgument.html

> Boolean arguments loudly declare that the function does more than one thing. They are confusing and should be eliminated.

Quoting http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524

> My reasoning here is that the separate methods communicate more clearly what my intention is when I make the call. Instead of having to remember the meaning of the flag variable when I see `book(martin, false)` I can easily read `regularBook(martin)`.

Additional discussion and reading material:

- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior
- https://medium.com/@amlcurran/clean-code-the-curse-of-a-boolean-parameter-c237a830b7a3
- https://8thlight.com/blog/dariusz-pasciak/2015/05/28/alternatives-to-boolean-parameters.html

Comment: Thanks. So I'm assuming that the logic for `create_whatever` will always exist in the code at the same level as `get_whatever`? In other words, should I keep that logic in the controller and not the model?

Comment: @cbunn the responsibility of a controller is to accept requests and delegate to the model. The model contains the actual logic to create or get whatever. So you will have both methods in both layers.

Comment: If I understand the concept of "code smell", the point is to describe things that are not actually bad of themselves,  or even lead to bad things, but are indicative of worse problems in the underlying code. If you are going to declare something code smell, then you have to say what it is indicative of, otherwise you are essentially just saying "I don't like it". (This is why I am tepid on  "code smell", it easily becomes a way to elevate personal style considerations into matters of good and bad)

Comment: @slackOverflow, I hear you, but I do think this is indicative of a problem. And I mentioned in the question that clarity might be improved. So I think that's the underlying issue. That it's not entirely clear what this flag does. In your answer, that intention became more clear, to be sure, but I think two functions achieves a better separation of concerns. This application is only being coded by me, but such issues might still make it more difficult to maintain in the long run.

Comment: @slackOverflow I expanded the answer. A code smell is a hint or heuristic that a particular piece code should be refactored to improve either that particular piece of code or the overall software quality.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a default value for create, so if you pass anything to it, it acts as a normal "get" operation for the database. Like this:

```
function get_class_instance($class_id, $date, $create = false);
```

You can query your ID's like this:

```
$class_id = get_class_instance(1, "18-10-2017");
```

You can then pass "true" to it whenever you need to create it on the database:

```
$class_id = get_class_instance(1, "18-10-2017", true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually just read about default values but didn't think to apply that here. I'll keep it in mind for the future, but I think @Gordon is right that this is bad form.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an optional parameter when you've got a sensible IDE with autocomplete feature. If it was a bad form, every language wouldn't have implemented this feature. Read More: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/22559/are-optional-parameters-helpful-or-a-hindrance-to-application-maintenance

Comment: It's not about having an *optional* parameter, but explicitly about having a boolean flag that causes a function to have *multiple behaviors*. Read more: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147977/is-it-wrong-to-use-a-boolean-parameter-to-determine-behavior

Comment: @Gordon, you are right, most of the code on the wild use methods like `first()` and `firstOrCreate()` for this operation. But it doesn't make this practice a bad one. That's my point. And, if you use it like `fopen`'s FILE_APPEND, FILE_CREATE flags, it'll be better of course.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing a number value, you can pass a real boolean value like this:

```
$original_cinstance_id = get_class_instance($original_class_id, $original_date, true);
```

Also in the declaration of your function, you can specify a default value to avoid to pass the boolean each time:

```
function get_class_instance($class_id, $date, $create = false)
```

Comment: Thanks. The difference between number value and boolean value wasn't what worried me. It was more that in either case, it would be difficult to know what the purpose of that flag was. So, I'll keep default values in mind for the future, but I think @Gordon is right that this is bad form.

Answer (score 1):

one option is to create an enumerator like so:

```
abstract class create_options {
    const no_action = 0;
     const create = 1;
}
```

so now your function call would look like this:

```
$original_cinstance_id = get_class_instance($original_class_id, $original_date, create_options::no_action);
```

in practice as long as your code is well commented then this isn't a major issue with boolean flags, but if you had a dozen possible options with different results then this could be useful.

As others have mentioned, in many languages you can also make an argument optional, and have a default behavior unless the caller specifically defines that argument.

Comment: i think this method is overkill. @TahaPasku method looks better

Comment: I agree it's overkill for this situation, I say as much at the end. Its still nice to know this option is out there though if the situation got more complicated.

Comment: I think this is the best solution - while you may be passing a boolean today, who know what you might want to pass tomorrow. You may have need for much richer context down the track, this solution offers that extensibility. Also, if you ever need to know where the `create` option is used in the code, you can use IDE tools to find usage of the class constant. The alternative, of using dynamically typed `0/false/null/[]/array()/etc.` values, is much harder to accurately and comprehensively track down across a code base.

Comment: Thanks. This is really clever and I'll keep it in mind for the future, but I think @Gordon is right that this is bad form.

Comment: As I commented above, I don't disagree with gordon per se, but he doesnt do more than say he doesnt like it with a fancy word. Gordon only says that passing boolean flags is bad form. Though its been a long time since I worked on something, what I describe above is ubiquitous in libraries. an example is SDL's window flags : https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WindowFlags having each of these as separate functions is impractical.

Comment: @slack fwiw, my answer was initially a comment. It was meant as a side note, hence it's not as detailed as my answers usually are. The OP asked me to put it as an answer though, so I did. If you reread my answer you will see that it does not contain any judgement of my own, but referencing a particular book. So it's not just *me not liking it with a fancy word*. Of course, you are of free to disagree with Robert Martin on the issue. Just to make sure: yes, you could use a enum. It makes the code more readable than a boolean flag. I'd accept it. Even though a create is not a get.